# Viewing all questions that once had a bounty

Tags: support

Recently, I was interested in viewing all questions that had a bounty set on them. The ["Featured"](https://math.stackexchange.com/?tab=featured) page lists the questions that currently have a bounty, but I couldn't figure out a way to view the questions with an expired bounty. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: There's [this query on data.SE](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematics/s/1508/).

Comment: @t.b.: It seems there's no better answer; I'm wondering whether to move on... Can you post that link as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I know is to use [this query on data.SE](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematics/s/1508/).

Since the database dumps are only updated every other month, the resulting list is bound to be somewhat out of date.